# Why does a request for a cached resource still fail with no network?

Tags: php, http, http-headers, cache-control

Why is it that when a static resource that uses the Cache-Control header, and with no Etag, does the browser still fail when the network disappears?

Is there a header that a server can return on the response to tell the browser to always fallback to the cached resource?

Comment: I believe it's because a header request has to be made to verify that a new version is not available.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but they slightly altered this behavior for service workers. I wonder if there is a way they could put it in h/2

Comment: can you please share all http headers which is returned in normal situation (when Cache-Control presented)?